# How to make iTunes skip to a specific time of a track? OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, itunes

I'm using `iTunes.h` to control and receive information from iTunes, but what I'd like to do is to be able to make iTunes skip to a specific time (in seconds, or something like that) of a track.
I found these methods --> `[iTunes fastForward]` and `[iTunes rewind]` but with these commands I can't specify the exact time.
Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for "player position". In AppleScript it goes:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    get player position
    set player position to 10
end tell
```

which translates to:

```
NSLog(@"%ld",[iTunes playerPosition]);
[iTunes setPlayerPosition:10];
```